# Copy-Paste in Mozilla Firefox and an irritating link

Tags: firefox

I am using Mozilla firefox and trying to copy paste a news article from this site :
www.indianexpress.com

however, whenever I do a copy paste of any text from the above news-site, an irritating link is also pasted in the word document in the last. This link says something like this : `see also... bla-blah + some link`.

Can someone tell me how to copy the the text without letting the `invisible link` also getting copied ?? thanks and regards.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/q/703744 (yes the question has the Chrome tag, but most of the answers are about Firefox). In particular, I would recommend disabling `dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled` in `about:config`.

Answer (score 1):

This feature of adding a link of the URL from where it was copied, at the end of copy-pasted content is [achieved through a JavaScript (typically using a service like Tynt Insight](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2010/12/how-tynt-insight-works.html)) so by disabling the specific external JavaScript file that contains code implementing this annoying feature using an add-on or any JavaScript from running after the page loads, you can get rid of the irritating message and link. (BTW, the monstrous home page of Indian Express measures over 4MB!).

[To disable JavaScript in Firefox (version 33)](http://mvark.blogspot.com/2014/10/how-to-disable-javascript-in-browser.html) after the page loads, in Firefox go to Tools > Web Developer > Inspector

In the panel that opens up, click on the Settings gear icon at the top right hand corner. Under Advanced Settings, check the option Disable JavaScript

[image]